# Is it safe to upload compiled Applescript files to Github?

Tags: security, github, applescript

`.scpt` Applescript files (written & saved using the Apple Inc. "Script Editor") are [a binary format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163134/why-are-script-editor-scpt-files-not-saved-as-plain-text-files).

Does the file save undo or historical information? For example, what if a previous version of the file contained a password or proprietary information?

Is it safe to share compiled files on Github?

Comment: No. Theres always a possibility to decompile Scripts or to read Strings written in clear format. even if its not easy - it is possible

Comment: I'm fairly sure undo information is not stored in the file. Obviously don't upload important passwords and whatnot, even in a "run-only" script file, since as Pat_Morita said it's absolutely possible to find strings in those, but you should otherwise be safe just uploading the scripts as they are.

Comment: That said, it's fairly easy to save a script in plain text (`.applescript`) format instead: just select "Text" in the Save or Export dialog. If you did that then people could also read the script and what it does before downloading.